How to compile more than 1 translation unit in a single C++ program
So I understand the difference between a translation unit and a .cpp file; however, I am trying to test how internal & external linkages work. I quote from my textbook:

Names having external linkage are available to other translation units.

How is it even possible for a name to be available to more than one translation unit? I believe you can compile more than one translation unit into a .obj file, but how can I do that in Visual Studio?
I know when you compile a file that has `#include"OTHER_FILE.cpp" then it's still one translation unit. I tried on looking on Stackoverflow about how to compile more than one translation unit in a C++ program, but all the posts explain what the difference between a file and a translation unit and not actually how to create more than one translation unit for a program.
Any explanation would be great.

You don’t. Each TU gets compiled to an individual object file. The linker then combines them together into an executable. (Fancy stuff lets you tell the compiler to do everything, so that it looks like you do it all at once... but multiple processes are happening in the background to make the single executable or library file)

Please note that it's a very bad habit to #include other sources file (e.g. .cpp files).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)

@Dúthomhas then how do I use external linkage in my program?

“External linkage” can mean several things. What do you mean by it?

Whenever you a) declare a function in a header, b) implement that function in one source file, and c) call it in another source file, you "use external linkage".

@Dúthomhas I mean a variable that can be accessed in more than one translation unit.

Define it in one source file. Declare it as extern in the other source file. With that said, global variables are a bad habit as well.

Same thing. You delcare that variable with extern specifier in the header, define it (without extern) in one source file, and refer to it in another.

The linker handles that. Simply declare that it exists (with the keyword extern), but do not define it.

It might be worth your time reading up on the structure of a C++ (or C) program. SO has a starting point here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work


I believe you can compile more than one translation unit into a .obj file, but how can I do that in Visual Studio?

You don't.  Each translation unit gets compiled into a separate object file.  The linker then links all of the object files that make up your program into a single executable.


How is it even possible for a name to be available to more than one translation unit?

The linker resolves such situations.  For instance, given
A.cpp
int foo = 0;

B.cpp
extern int foo;

int do_stuff()
{
    foo = 42;
}

A.cpp and B.cpp are each compiled as separate translation units, resulting in A.obj and B.obj.  When linking the final executable, the linker sees the reference to foo in B.obj and is able to find foo in A.obj because its name has external linkage.
If instead A.cpp declared
static int foo = 0;

linking would fail.  The linker would not be able to find the foo in A.obj because names declared static in global or namespace scope have internal linkage.

The entire purpose of header files (.hpp files) is to declare things that exist inside the corresponding source file. That way other source files can use it.
quux.hpp
#ifndef QUUX_HPP
#define QUUX_HPP

// Here we declare that a variable named ‘quux_value’ exists in “quux.cpp”
// and it can be accessed by code in other .cpp files.
extern int quux_value;

// Here we declare that a function named ‘quuxify’ exists in “quux.cpp”
// and it can be invoked by code in other .cpp files.
int quuxify( int );

#endif

Our quux.cpp might then look like this:
#include "quux.hpp"

int quux_value = 1;

int quuxify( int x )
{
    return x * quux_value;
}

If we wish to have things in our .cpp file that are not available to other .cpp files, simply do not declare them in the .hpp file.
Now my main program can use the “quux” stuff by

including the quux.hpp header definitions, and
linking with the compiled quux.o object file.

#include <iostream>
#include "quux.hpp"

int main()
{
    quux_value = 3;
    std::cout << quuxify( 4 ) << "\n";
}

There are two translation units: “quux” and whatever you named the file containing main().
Compile and link them together into an executable and it’ll print out 12.

EDIT: BTW, this is a bit of a simplified explanation, but it is correct and will get you started. Just be aware that there are further shades to visibility that are not mentioned here.


I tried on looking on Stackoverflow about how to compile more than
one translation unit in a C++ program:

In Visual Studio, right click your project-> C/C++-> general -> Suppress Startup Banner: Set No
Then you will see the cl command when building project.
cl /c /W3 ... ... ConsoleApplication.cpp MyClass.cpp.
Also see the MSVC Compiler Command-Line Syntax doc
